# Anchor carousel navigation HTML to bottom of image using only CSS (without CSS grid)

Tags: html, css, carousel

In the example image, I have navigation. Example code below shows potential markup. If the image **and** the text below need to move together (slide side to side), how can I anchor the position the navigation using only CSS. I suspect that I'll have to rely on some JavaScript without knowing heights of elements, but I would rather not have to.

To be clear, the navigation here *appears* to be centered, but they are not. They need to be floated at the bottom of an arbitrary image height.

[image: Carousel with sandwiched navigation]

**UPDATE**

Example code [(see CodePen)](https://codepen.io/arxpoetica/pen/qpRVKe):

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="indices">
        <a href="#"><div class="dot"><div class="ghost">Carousel slide 1</div></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="dot"><div class="ghost">Carousel slide 2</div></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="dot"><div class="ghost">Carousel slide 3</div></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="gutter">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="img"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/25/13/55/horses-1414889_1280.jpg" alt="Horses"></div>
            <div class="text">This text content can really be any arbitrary height, so it wouldn’t work to just use negative margins on the navigation, unfortunately.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="img"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Nokota_Horses_cropped.jpg" alt="Other Horses"></div>
            <div class="text">Also, images can be arbitrary heights.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="img"><img src="http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/640/Water-Turtle-Nature-Reptile-649667.jpg" alt="Turtles"></div>
            <div class="text">Turtles</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <a class="item prev" href="#" aria-label="Previous carousel story"></a>
        <a class="item next" href="#" aria-label="Next carousel story"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code is very flexible; I can move things around if need be.

Comment: and your code ?

Comment: are you looking for absolute positioned elements?? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: please post you code and explain better what you are trying to do

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I'm happy to post code, but what isn't clear in my description?

Comment: Please clarify that **They need to be floated at the bottom of an arbitrary image height**

Comment: Updated with code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use position: relative and position: absolute (like in this  [simple example](https://codepen.io/livie7/pen/QadOqq))? You wrap your image slide and bullet navigation in a div where you set the position to relative. Then set the navigation wrapper to absolute position (bottom: 0 to place it at the bottom of the parent div). It will normally stay in place even if the image changes as the height of the parent div will depend on the img height.

```
.outer-div { 
  position: relative;
 }

.bullet-nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* to center nav */
}
```

Comment: This works great if the navigation needs to be in the center, but in my description I state it needs to be anchored to the bottom of the image, so I don't think this works. This is great though if it can just be centered.